# The object of "Address a concern on"

Tags: objects

I came across a sentence below:

> Its purpose is to address a concern on the part of the xxx staff that
> conceptual models of processes constitute a major source of
> uncertainty. (xxx is the name of an organization)

My understanding is that "some of the staff in xxx" worry about the conceptual models. I thought the sentence should be

> Its purpose is to address a concern by the part of the xxx staff that
> conceptual models of processes constitute a major source of
> uncertainty.

Is this correct?

Comment: It would be "marginally" acceptable to *address a concern **by*** (or ***of*** or ***from***) *the xxx staff [that blah blah was a matter of concern to them]*. But the version as actually given above is probably best unless we go in for more radical rephrasing to avoid the relatively complex structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The phrase "on the part of" is an English idiom. "By the part of" would be incorrect.

See here: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/on%20the%20part%20of

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you!